# How do i make these doubles public?

Tags: java, double

How do i make the double variables below (mon, tues, wed, etc) available publically throughout my application that i am making? Like for example if i go after the last curly bracket the mon variable can not be accesed. Any ideas?

```
    finalize.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                double mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());
                double tues = Double.parseDouble(tuesday.getText());
                double wed = Double.parseDouble(wednesday.getText());
                double thurs = Double.parseDouble(thursday.getText());
                double fri = Double.parseDouble(friday.getText());
                double sat = Double.parseDouble(saturday.getText());
                double sun = Double.parseDouble(sunday.getText());

                double sum = mon + tues + wed + thurs + fri + sat + sun;



           }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare them on class level, as fields.

The inner class can access final local variables of the enclosing method, but that won't work in your case as you change the values.

```
class MyClass {

    double mon = 0.;  // <- declare it as a field

    void myMethod() {
      finalize.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());  // <- accessible
           }
      });
      System.out.println(mon);  // <- accessible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to create class member variables like so:

```
private double mon = 0.0;
private double tues = 0.0;
// etc.
```

and to create public getter methods if you wish to access them externally:

```
public double getMon() {
  return mon;
}
```

getSum can be represented in a single method:

```
public double getSum() {
     return mon + tues + wed + thurs + fri + sat + sun;
}
```

Don't forget to remove the local declaration in your actionPerformed method then:

```
mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());
```

Comment: Technically you are creating class members rather than global variables. Also this approach allows you to not define a field for sum and simply have it as a method call 'public double getSum() { return sun+mon+... ; }`

Answer (score 2):

Define them on class level. For example if you class is named `MyClass` do something like following:

```
class MyClass {
    public mon;
    //......
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());
    //......
    } 
}
```

BUT never define public variables. Use bean notation instead:

```
class MyClass {
    private mon;
    //......
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());
    //......
    } 

    public double getMon() {
         return mon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating the variable outside of the listener, and only modify it in the listener.